# Nginx set custom variables to get them in Ruby project as possible in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, environment-variables

How to set my custom variables in nginx config file of my hosting to get this variable e.g. as ENV["customvariable"] in my Ruby app?

I'd like to create 1 app with multiple hostings and change loaded variables with gem 'settingslogic' dependent on my nginx set variable.

E.g.:

nginx conf. file

`"CUSTOMVAR='asdf'"`

Ruby app:

`<%= ENV["CUSTOMVAR"] %>`

Browser:

`asdf`

thx

Answer (score 1):

You are able to add headers on your nginx layer and then read them on the application layer.

To add header to your backend server you could try [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)

And then you'll be able to read on your controllers with request.headers["header_name"]